# excel formula, if, and, or?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am making an Excel form to use in housing.  I want to be able to enter a date in one cell (tenancy end date) and calculate the number of days empty in the next cell (void days).  I then have another column with date *re-let*.

I have managed to get it so that the *void days* column will stop calculating when a date is entered in the *re-let* column.  Every week, I have to report on the number of void days for all the properties - this will be easy if I have a tenancy end date on each line, however, I don't.  This means that when I copy the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(J6),TODAY()-H6)` onto the next line, excel inputs 42995 - not good when I want to add up that column.

I found a formula `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(J11),ISBLANK(H11)),0,TODAY()-H11)` to put a zero in the void days column, HOWEVER, I need it to calculate the number of void days still if there is a date in the tenancy ended column BUT, to stop calculating the number of void days when a date is entered in re-let date.  I use excel by googling a lot, so, I am not an expert, just a good googler!

Comment: the two formula's cell references aren't the same as the two formulas are in different cells.

Comment: I think this is what I need.  If 'tenancy end date' is blank AND 're-let date' is blank then ENTER 0.  If 'tenancy end date' is entered, then calculate number of void days from todays date.  If there is a 'tenancy end date' and 're-let date' then calculate number of void days based on the 're-let' date.

Comment: Good job showing what you tried.  You could have really improved your question by adding some sample data that poeple could cut and paste.  Its better than a photo as that way multiple people will not be retyping the data.  Dont worry if the format looks bad, lots on here that can format it to make it look pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: POC]

Assuming your data is layed out as above, place the following formula in B2 and copy down.

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(C2="",TODAY()-A2,IF(C2>=A2,C2-A2,"Re-Let While occupied")))
```

- It will calculate compared to the current date when the the cell in C
  is empty
- It will calculate compared to the rel-let date when there is
  a value in C
- It will leave a blank when the cell in column A is empty
- It will toss and error message to you when the end date is larger
  then the relet date.

E2 was simply:

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

Comment: The one case I did not show was if you had a date in C and A was empty.  It would be the same results as row 5

Comment: Assuming that just numerical numbers are used, then your formula can be shortened to `=IF(A2,IF(C2,IF(C2>=A2,C2-A2,"Re-Let While occupied"),TODAY()-A2),"")`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the only cases are:

- A2=empty & C2=empty
- A2=date & C2=empty
- A2=date & C2=date & C2 >= A2 (so no negative void-days can occur)

---

```
=IF(A2,IF(C2,C2,TODAY())-A2,"")
```

Having the same as before but C2 can be smaller than A2 and you want to count as 0 days:

```
=IF(A2,MAX(IF(C2,C2,TODAY())-A2,0),"")
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough...I'd love to say it seems simple now....well, it does now that I know the formula and I can follow it....I would never have gotten it myself though!